# Apache Camel: How do we parse URL path for Servlet input and then use it as parameters in SQL output

Tags: apache-camel

I'd wish to create a general restful service to perform crud operations using Camel, but without using Restlet, just plain Servlet and SQL components.

I am familiar with Camel for 2 days only, and I am not able to get URL parts in order to use them in SQL query.

The idea is to use only XML configuring. I tried many doferent ways, came to using javascript. Here's my code so far (below).

I can't get how to check the url path, parse out it's parts, put into "message body" which should be a source for parameters for SQL query.

In this particular scenario it says, "ReferenceError: "response" is not defined".

```
    <route>
        <from uri="servlet:///crud?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
        <setBody>
            <javaScript><![CDATA[
                  request.headers.get("CamelHttpPath").match(/\/(\w+)\/(\w*)/)
            ]]></javaScript>
        </setBody>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <javaScript><![CDATA[
                    request.headers.get("CamelHttpMethod") == "GET" && 
                    response.body != null
                ]]></javaScript>
                <to uri="sql:select * from person where id=2?dataSource=dataSource"></to>
            </when>
            <when>
                <xpath>$CamelHttpMethod = 'POST'</xpath>
                <transform>
                    <simple>Update!!! path - ${header.CamelHttpPath}, url - ${header.CamelHttpUrl}, uri = ${header.CamelHttpUri}, base uri = ${header.CamelHttpBaeUri}. And request is ${header.CamelHttpServletRequest}</simple>
                </transform>
            </when>
            <when>
                <xpath>$CamelHttpMethod = 'PUT'</xpath>
                <transform>
                    <simple>Insert</simple>
                </transform>
            </when>
            <when>
                <xpath>$CamelHttpMethod = 'DELETE'</xpath>
                <transform>
                    <simple>Delete...</simple>
                </transform>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <transform>
                    <simple>Unsupported method ${header.CamelHttpMethod} (${header.CamelHttpPath})</simple>
                </transform>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
```

Comment: Why is `CamelHttpPath` matched with `match(/\/(\w+)\/(\w*)/)` and written to the body (the result is of type `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeArray`)? And why do you test for `response.body != null` which may result to the error message? Could you give as an example for `CamelHttpPath` and the result you expect?

Comment: For example, "/person/2"

Comment: I want to parse out "person" and "2"

Comment: Why not using REST? Did you already spot the Restlet component: https://camel.apache.org/restlet.html?

Comment: I run it in a webapp and here http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html they advice to include Spring extention to Restlet, and it seems to depend on the wrong version of Spring. I use 4.0.4.

Comment: I also use plain servlet and http in the same web application for other part of the service

Comment: @Peter I ended up with using Restlet, thanks. I somehow switched off the duplicates of Spring and the Restlet itself.
Thank you! Let's leave this, if there is a solution without restlet.